# SQL injection and ImageResizer SQL Reader Plugin

Tags: sql-injection, imageresizer

Started using the [imageresizer](http://imageresizing.net/) for .NET, and it works great. The only thing I'm wondering about is the possiblity for SQL injection when using the SQL Reader.

Is it safe to use a query in the config settings? Will the SQL Reader plugin take care of sanitizing and eliminating SQL Injections?

Answer (score 1):

SqlReader ([see the source code on github](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/master/Plugins/SqlReader/SqlReader.cs#L202)) uses SQL parameters, making SQL injection  impossible.

What custom SQL are you using that made you concerned about an injection attack?